# What exactly is a "Wound Rank" in L5R

Tags: l5r

It's been a while since I've played L5R. I don't understand what the book means by Wound Rank. It could mean things like Healthy, Nicked, etc. or it could be individual points of damage. Which does it mean? If it is the former, does the Disadvantage Permanent Injury fill up the Healthy, or is Healthy not a wound rank considering it's the state you exist in before you're wounded?

Comment: I think we all kind of assumed you meant 4e, but what edition did you actually mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In L5R, like so many other mechanics, Wound Rank does indeed refer to the various categories of wound, such as Healthy, Nicked etc. The individual points of damage are usually referred to as Wound Points.

This mirrors the mechanics used for Glory Points/Ranks and Honor Points/Ranks, and even Shadowlands Points/Ranks. A number of Wound or Damage points equal to or greater than a Wound Rank means you suffer the effects of that Rank.

About the Permanent Injury, yes, it fills up the Healthy Wound Rank. A character is considered to be at whatever Wound Rank is not completely filled, so normally, up until Wound Points equal to the Healthy Rank, he would be Healthy. This character is never Healthy.

(Additional info) There is a definition for wounds on p82 of the 4e rulebook, and p166 of the 3e rulebook.

3e actually talks about Wound levels rather than Wound Ranks, but then, so does Permanent Wound (p117). 4e distinguishes between points of damage and Wound Ranks, and Permanent Wound fills in your first Wound Rank (p161). Earlier editions may have used less exact terminology.

Comment: I feel like this answer could be improved a bit, the OP (and myself to some extent) seem to be confused about the mechanical effects of Permanent Wound and I can't figure out from your answer which of the two(?) possible interpretations should be applied here. 1) That your Healthy rank is always full and you fill in your first wound in the Nicked box instead. 2) That you fill in from Healthy as normal, but are considered Nicked while Healthy. I'd err in the direction of the latter but your answer reads like the former is true: "it fills up the Healthy Wound Rank". Could you clarify this?

Comment: makes me feel like the disadvantage should be worth more points considering by default healthy is the largest chunk of "Hit Points" you have.

Comment: I'll add some more clarity once I'm at home, and have a rulebook to read for reference - what edition were you looking at? 4th?

Comment: i dont actually know. i will need to dig out my book.

Answer (score 2):

A Wound is an individual point of damage. A Wound Rank is an overall level of Wounds inflicted. If you read the the section on **Wounds**, you will see that the **Healthy** Wound Rank is not filled until you take **Earth**x5 Wounds. **Permanent Wound** causes your **Healthy** Wound Rank to become permanently filled.

From L5R 4th Edition Core, pg 82, **Wounds**

> Individual characters have Wound Ranks that measure the amount of damage that they can sustain before it begins to impair their ability to take actions and eventually incapacitates or kills them. **The Wounds inflicted by an attack fill up these Wound Ranks in order**, with each Rank containing a maximum number of Wounds determined by the character's Earth Ring.

From L5R 4th Edition Core, pg 161, **Permanent Wound**

> Your first Wound Rank is always considered full.

**Healthy** is the first Wound Rank listed under **Wounds**. As the portion I highlighted shows, the Wound Ranks are filled up in order. Since one cannot use Wounds to "fill up" a Wound Rank that is already full, your first Wound must go into the **Nicked** Wound Rank.

Were you to use the interpretation that "considered" means the Wound Rank can still be filled, this Disadvantage would have literally no penalty. It is not until Wounds have been placed within the **Nicked** Wound Rank that you begin taking the +3 TN penalty associated with it. In addition, had they intended the Disadvantage to give a "virtual" penalty they would have used wording more like that found on page 268 for the Kiho **Stain Upon the Soul**.

It is very important to remember that the point gains for Disadvantages are not equivalent to the point costs for Advantages or even Rings or Skills. The Disadvantage **Weakness** provides one of the easiest places to illustrate this. It costs you 4 times the new value to raise Traits and the default level of traits is 2. Even if we use the most generous interpretation of the disadvantage (in which you literally reduce your Trait by 1 which would make the phrasing extremely odd) you still only gain 6XP for something that will cost you 8XP to regain. Likewise, Cursed by the Realm grants you 4 points, but Touched by the Realm costs you 5.